# Are questions about cinematography allowed?

Tags: discussion

I see in the FAQ that questions about a Movie/TV show's production are allowed. But "production" (at least to me) is vague.

But I have a specific question about a technique used to film certain types of scenes. Are these questions allowed?

Comment: preliminary thoughts say why not. fetting too technical might be ok on avp.stackexcange.com though

Comment: I don't see why not either, but we won't be the best people to answer very technical stuff.

Comment: Yes they are allowed and we previously have some of them, you can go through this list http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film-techniques?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Answer (score 3):

To flesh out my comment (I was on mobile, too frustrating to write an answer).

Technical production questions are **on-topic** here, however, asking on [AVP.SE](http://avp.stackexchange.com) is a better bet for *really* technical questions.

(I'd ask on their meta first honestly, don't know off the top of my head whats *off-topic* for them)

Comment: Anyways we have Nobby/oliver so their is no problem with technical question. And we don't need AVP :P